# How to draw this diagram?

Tags: technical-drawing

[image]

I don't know how to draw this by latex.

Comment: Hi Sara. In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification.

Comment: -1: Please show some attempt you've made in achieving this and specify what you're struggling with. The point of this Q&A site is to solve specific problems, not to have other people do your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [tikz-cd](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). It bases on TikZ, so you could use TikZ commands and and styles too, but it provides another syntax for such diagrams, arrows and styles, which may be handy with complex diagrams. Your example with tikz-cd:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
  commutative diagrams/.cd,
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>=space}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
               & A \arrow{d}            &              \\
               & B \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr} &              \\
  C \arrow{dr} &                        & D \arrow{dl} \\
               & F                      &              \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram example]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need but I have problem with {tikz-cd}!

Comment: @Sara You need to install it. It's pretty new. Have a look at the many "How to install" or "How to update" questions and answers, specific for your TeX system. See also: [tikz-cd documenation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-cd).

Comment: While I really like this answer -- it makes things really easy for some as TikZ-ignorant as me -- I'm having a hard time seeing how it complies with our discussion at [Should we answer really bad questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414)

Comment: @doncherry Sara is pretty new on the site. Somebody could help her improving the question or edit it. Together with the already provided answers, there's value then. She did not show effort by code, but by hand-drawing and uploading. I did not see much reason for parenting by holding back recommendations. Besides that, I guess, this draft is intended to get a start for more complex, self-written diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pgf-tikz? Something like this (untested) might work:

```
\begin {tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a);
\path (a) +(0,-1) coordinate (b);
\path (b) +(-1,-1) coordinate (c);
\path (b) +(1,-1) coordinate (d);
\path (c) +(1,-1) coordinate (f);
\draw (a) node {A} -- 
      (b) node {B} -- 
      (c) node [left]{C} -- 
      (f) node {F} -- 
      (d) node [right]{D} -- 
      (b);
\end {tikzpicture}
```

You could also look at using the `to` operation to join the letters ('nodes').  See the tikz [tutorial/manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to do this. Inkscape has the ability to export a combination pdf and tex file. You then use `\input{myfigure.tex}` and you'll get the image and any text will be the same font as the rest of your document.